# DC boost converter and Ohm's Law

Tags: dc-dc-converter

A circuit has a resistance of 1 Ohm, a DC power supply rated at 9W is delivering power to the circuit. Using a DC boost-converter that takes in an input of 9W can it output different voltages? Even if the resistance is 1 ohm?

If the resistance is 1 Ohm and the power is 9W, from ohms law voltage is 3V and current is 3A, but can I use a DC boost converter to increase voltage to higher voltages?

EDIT: The location of the resistor is between power supply and the load, if a converter or constant current was added, the resistor will be after the converter/constant current source and before the load.

Comment: When you refer to "A circuit has a resistance of 1 Ohm". Do you mean that there is a 1 Ohm resistor between the DC Power Supply and the load? Or that the load is 1 Ohm?

Comment: resistor between the PS and Load.

Comment: @Key Please provide a complete schematic with power source, converter, resistor (and load).

Comment: @Key I think we aswered under different assumptions on what you are really asking. Could you please, update a little bit your original question? Where is exactly located the 1Ohm resistor? Between Power supply and converter OR as the load at the output of the converter? Thank you!

Comment: @Key it seems to me that you forgot the load in your first description/in your thoughts. Or I'm misunderstanding the question again. Please provide a schematic to prevent further misunderstandings. (Your can even draw them on Stackoverflow, you do not even have to leave the site)

Comment: I forgot to say that the load is anything from a motor, light bulb, etc... after the resistor, so imagine a PS of 9W then a converter/ constant current circuit source then resistor then the load. The idea is to have different values of voltage that will always equal 9W. You and @jose.angel.jimenez stated that it is possible to have for example 9V at 1A(if it was 100% which it isn't) but the principle of converting voltage into a higher value is possible but of course of the cost of lower current, or 3V at 3A or even 4.5V at 2A. As long as P = IV = 90W.

Comment: 9W* Sorry, the 90W was a mistake.

Comment: @Key You can have e.g. 9V output voltage. But in that case you can not force the output to 1A and not change the load. 9W is the maximum power you can supply, how much current flows in reality depends on the load, the supply just sets the upper limit. Same with a current source where the source holds the current constant, but the voltage on the load will vary according to the load. By changing the supply / DC/DC converter you can just set one, either current or voltage, the other one settles itself according to the load (within the capabilities of the supply).

Comment: @AndreasWallner What do you mean by changing the load? Why can't the load take 9V at 1A? I have circuits that require varying voltages at constant currents, say it requires 1A and the resistance is 1 Ohm, and requires voltage from 1V to 30V, so the required power supply would have to be about 30W?

Comment: @Key It comes down to ohms law: R=U*I. 9V != 1Ohm*1A. It may be that you have circuits that require varying voltages at constant currents, but the resistance will not always be 1Ohm. If you have a constant current of 1A through a resistor of 1Ohm you will have 1V across that resistor and not something between 1V and 30V. In any other case you do not have a purely resistive load (e.g. motor, etc.) but that is than a completely different story. Which is why I wanted a complete schematic of your use-case.

Comment: Hm, I'm confused with a lot of things @AndreasWallner due to my lack of knowledge, but my goal honestly was trying to maintain the same current to a certain load and it turns out that a constant current source can easily do that. I watched a simple video on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hgrvJ2b2xfg   that shows you the powersupply applying varying voltages (high or low) and the current stays the same, while it's a bit confused when I think about ohms law.

Comment: Thankfully I understood of the idea "a bit". But amazing how a circuit like this can do such things! Also unbelievable how there are constant current sources that would automatically change the voltage instead of manually adjusting them.

Comment: The thing about the video you saw: There you do not have a resistive load that is e.g. 1Ohm. The load is an active circuit that is built to always sink 50mA. This is not a simple resistor. Simply said, the circuit changes its resistance so that regardless of voltage, it always sinks the same current (and you still have R=U*I). You can in no way compare this just a resistor.

Comment: @AndreasWallner I agree, however, the point or main thing I wanted to know is would it be possible...  to have high voltage at low current applied yet always equaling out to 9W, and it seems that it can(based on my understanding from your answer and jose's).

Comment: @Key Ok, it may be that our answers where not clear enough, so in just a few words: if you have a 1Ohm resistor, there is only one possible case to have 9W of power dissipated in the resistor, and that case is with 9V and 1A. There is no other possible voltage/current pair that would dissipate 9W on a 1Ohm resistor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*The text below is only valid for an ideal resistor (e.g. one without parasitic effects, which should be good enough for the considerations below)*

For the answer below I interpreted the question as to ask for information on this schematic:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmSW4s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Since you did not mention any voltages, I'll answer a little bit more generic:

It is not possible is to have a resistor that does not adhere to Ohms law (R=U/I). A simple resistor will adhere to this law/equation at all times, therefore:
If you want to build a boost converter that outputs e.g. 5V into a 1 Ohm load, it will have to deliver 25W of power. (P = U^2 / R). This is certainly possible.

But: The boost converter would need to be supplied with enough energy to do that. If your boost converter has an efficiency of e.g. 85%, you would need to supply the converter with ~30W. In this case, your power supply would not be sufficient.

A DC/DC converter can not produce energy/power out of nothing. It is a tool to change the voltage of some supply to another voltage with acceptable losses, nothing more.

If you only have a 9W power supply you can never supply a resistor with a voltage higher than 3V (U = sqrt(P*R), same eq. as above, and that only if you have an efficiency of 100%), you simply do not have the power.

What will happen if you try depends on your power supply.

Some of the possibilities:

- The power supply might switch itself off, since your exceeded its specification
- The power supply might go into current limitation (and basically become a constant current source)
- The power supply might oscillate
- The power supply might get to hot and destroy itself (hopefully not, but many cheap and or badly designed ones do)

Regardless of that, you can not have a resistor e.g. dissipate 20W of power on a 9W supply.

*Edit: Further explanation regarding "constant current mode"*

Regarding your second comment, and my point about the constant current source. This was just meant as an explanation what a real-world power supply might do if you try to consume more power than the power supply can deliver. Behaving like a constant current source is one thing that can happen in that case:

Some power sources (e.g. most lab supplies) are built in a way that they have a set voltage and a set current. Whichever one is the one that is the limiting point at the moment, will be the one used. Say we set the power supply to 1V and 1A, and connect a variable resistor. When you turn the variable resistor to its maximum resistance e.g. 10k the power supply will be in constant voltage mode (voltage at 1V and current at I=U/R=100uA). If you turn the resistance down, e.g. 0.5 Ohm, the power supply will go into constant current mode (current at 1A, voltage at U=I*R=500mV). But the power delivered will never exceed 1W (P=U*I)

Comment: Can you explain the point about constant current source? - Also, the idea of having more power in this case 25W is not only increasing voltage but also increasing current from 3A, Isn't it possible to only increase the voltage without increasing current?(Highly related to constant current source).

Comment: A constant current source only increases voltage, without changing the current so it could possible increase 100Volts while current stays 3A, and the resistance did not change(since the only change variable is voltage).

Comment: For your first point: No it is not possible. Current through and voltage across a resistor have to adhere to Ohms Law (R=U/I) at all times, so it is simply not possible to just increase the voltage, without the current getting bigger.

Comment: I just edited my answer, the space in the comments was not big enough ;) . Is my edit of the answer sufficient, or do you have further questions?

Comment: "It is not possible is to have a resistor that does not adhere to Ohms law" On the contrary I'd say it's impossible to find a resistor that does adhere exactly to ohm's law.

Comment: @ThePhoton You are right, it would have been better to write 'resistance' instead of 'resistor'. I think that should make the answer correct? For the purpose of the OPs question I wanted to write it with strong wording, but yes, this way the answer is not correct. Or just write 'ideal resistor'...? I'm not an English native speaker, I'm not sure if one can use 'resistance' in this context.

Comment: @AndreasWallner Well I guess constant current source might be the nearest thing to what I'm looking for, having varying voltages at the same current is one thing that is reasonable.

Comment: @Key Depends on your application which you have said nothing about. But: The same I have written above also applies to current sources. If you have a 9W power source, you can not dissipate more power in the resistor than 9W, so in your case you would not be able to go beyond 3A/3V for your power supply (as you calculated) no matter which type of dc/dc converter you use. You can not violate the law of conservation of energy. If you tell us what your application is we might be able to provide better information.

Comment: @AndreasWallner I don't mean to go beyond P=IV, I mean 9W can be changed into different values of V that will still equal 9W, say 4.5V at 2A. Constant current sources that will increase voltage to maintain current will require a bit more power of course supplied in and so forth...

Comment: @Key You are right that P=I*V can be changed to different values, but you have to keep your resistor in mind. As I wrote: For the resistor U=R*I has to be true at all times. You therefore can not have 4.5V and 2A (since 4.5V <> 1Ohm * 2A). This is simply not possible with a resistive load.
9W is the *maximum* output of you power supply, which current flows will depend on your load (since you have a constant voltage supply). If the current "demanded" by the load is higher than the supply can deliver, the power supply will simply cease to function correctly.

Comment: @AndreasWallner I'm confused between your post and jose.angel's post.

Comment: Ohm's law says V is *proportional to* I, in other words that resistance is a constant for any given conductor. In real conductors the resistance changes with things like temperature, which may itself change according to the current flowing in the conductor, so real conductors are inevitably 'non-Ohmic' to some extent.

Comment: @nekomatic It is still Ohmic because voltage and current are still proportional. Its just that the "resistor" changes its resistance, but Ohm's law still holds (ignoring parasitic capacitive/inductive effects). I do not know how you get from "V is proportional to I" to "resistance is constant" the simply does not imply the latter.

Comment: @AndreasWallner I think you need to look up the definition of 'proportional'. If Ohm's law didn't imply a constant resistance there would be no such thing as a non-Ohmic conductor. Check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law . Your answer is a good one otherwise and I've upvoted it.

Comment: @AndreasWallner As long as I can convert the voltage(which is my goal) to higher values using a dc/dc converter that is what's important. So, if a 9W power input is supplied a DC converter can output that to whatever value of voltage that is, as long as P=IV = 9W, and of course there are some losses due to efficiency problem. My question did not hint more power outputted via the converter, my question was outputting more voltage of course at the cost of lower currents. Which is practical to do, whatever the load/ or where the resistance is.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very interesting question about the *fundamentals of energy conservation, power transfer/dissipation and efficiency*, in the context of **boost converters**.

**Short answer**, quoting your questions:

> A circuit has a resistance of 1 Ohm, a DC power supply rated at 9W is
>   delivering power to the circuit. Using a DC boost-converter that takes
>   in an input of 9W can it output different voltages? Even if the
>   resistance is 1 ohm?

Yes. Of course, it will depend on the specific boost converter design. However, **in general, a boost converter will raise the input voltage up to an output voltage independently of its series path resistance**. That's why they are also called step-up converters. As it is explained below in more detail, *the series path resistance (of which your 1 Ohm resistor is now part of), will INCREASE the power losses (reduce the overall EFFICIENCY)*, **having little impact on the capability of the boost converter to raise the output voltage**.

> If the resistance is 1 Ohm and the power is 9W, from ohms law voltage
>   is 3V and current is 3A, but can I use a DC boost converter to
>   increase voltage to higher voltages?

**You are applying Ohm's law as if the boost converter was a short-circuit to ground!** *Your calculation of 3V/3A is right only if you put the 9W source directly on the 1Ohm resistor*.

A boost converter will demand current in repetitive pulses, usually in two phases: 1) *Demand of current following a linear or exponential curve, from 0 to a certain value of Amps, while using that current to "charge-up" an internal storage component (inductor or capacitor)*. 2) *Without demanding current from the power source, the energy from the storage component is transferred to the output (load), while raising its voltage*.

---

**Long answer**. First, some context and background that will be used for the reasoning below:

- **A boost converter** is a type of **SMPS** (Switched Mode Power Supply) **where the DC output voltage is higher than the DC input voltage**. It is commonly said the *the input voltage is raised up to the output voltage*.
- A boost converter **usually works in two or more timed stages**,

  1. During the first phase, *some energy is captured from the external power supply* (DC voltage input) *and stored*.
  2. During the second phase, *the stored energy is transferred to the load while raising the output voltage*.
- We will consider here a **basic generic topology: the single inductor flyback boost converter operating in DCM (Discontinuous-Conduction Mode)**, which *will serve us for arriving some conclusions without losing generalization*. We could equally well arrive the same conclusions using any other well known topologies, for instance those using capacitors instead of inductors.

Now, **we have a single inductor which will serve us for storing some energy** during the *first phase of the conversion*:

- Let's say that the first phase lasts for \$T_{on}\$. During that time, the boost converter will connect the input voltage directly to the inductor, so that the inductor will start "charging-up" energy. An ideal inductor (no parasitic capacitance or resistance), will increase its current linearly up to its maximum allowed current (called saturation current). Let's suppose \$T_{on}\$ is short enough so that the saturation current is not reached, then:

  \$I_{inductor} (t) = \frac{V_{input}}{L}.t \$, where the slope of the curve is \$\frac{V_{input}}{L}\$.
- At the end of \$T_{on}\$, the energy stored in the inductor is:
  \$E_{inductor} = \frac{1}{2}L.I_{T_{on}}^2\$
- Getting to the point, now we can see that all the resistors in the series path between the input voltage and the inductor will dissipate (loss) some power (heat), according to the Ohm's Law:
  \$P_{losses}(t) = R.{I(t)}^2\$
- As the current curve is approximately linear (now the effect of R in the circuit makes the current curve to actually be an exponential curve), we can integrate the energy lost in the resistor:
  \$E_{losses}=\int{P_{losses}(t)}.dt=\frac{1}{3}R.I_{T_{on}}^3\$
- And we reach a rough estimation of the efficiency of our converter for the first phase of the conversion:

  \$\rho=\frac{E_{inductor}}{E_{inductor}+E_{losses}}=\frac{1}{1+\frac{2}{3}\frac{R}{L}}\$
- Where in the equation above you can substitute R for the total series path resistance of your circuit: physical resistors, intrinsic resistance of the switching elements (MOSFET?) and equivalent series resistance of your inductor.
- The above is only a first order approximation (simplified) for the case of a single flyback inductor boost converter. The real, more accurate calculation will add the second phase/stage of the converter and all the devices in your circuit.

For a more in-depth introduction to the topic, you can check this article by Texas Instruments:

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva061/slva061.pdf

Comment: I'm confused between your post and @AndreasWallner's post.

Comment: @jose.angel.jimenez I do not get your answer in this context. There is simply no way to have a DC/DC converter that outputs 20W if it is supplied by a power source that can deliver only 9W. But this is exactly what the OP is asking for. Sure you can have a converter with an output voltage of 9V in that case, but it could only source 1A (conservation of energy and at 100% efficiency), which is not enough to drive a load of 1 Ohm. The load is simply to big (power) / low (resistance).

Comment: @Andreas. The OP is asking confirmation about output voltages (not wattages). Of course, you cannot output more power than input power. Where is he saying about outputting more than 9W?

Comment: The 1Ohm is not the load, it is a resistor between the power supply and the converter (I asked for confirmation on this specific point). That was my understanding when I wrote the answer. Anyhow, I will re-check everything. Thank you.

Comment: @Key I think we aswered under different assumptions on what you are really asking. Could you please, update a little bit your original question? Where is exactly located the 1Ohm resistor? Between Power supply and converter OR as the load at the output of the converter? Thank you!

Comment: @jose.angel.jimenez Ok, now I get your answer. Sorry for the bother, I see where we interpreted the question differently.

Comment: @AndreasWallner Nothing to worry about. I am here to share and learn.

Comment: @AndreasWallner  Updated the location of the resistor, and thank you both for clearing things out!

Answer (score -1):

9 Watt power means P=V*I but normally voltage will be constant ,but how much current we can drown from the ckt will be decided by the manufacture of the component.
Ex: 4.5v*2A=9W ,5v*1.8A=9W in this case power is same but current and voltage will varied,hence in power calculation current is measure roll, we are not take directly  1V*9A=9W  ,if in datasheet manufacture is mentioned about current means not a problem..u can boost the voltage.

Comment: This answer isn't coherent at all in it's current state.